# How to resolve 'system:error:invalid-token' In Nexmo Vonage SDK changing to a new app in the same account

Tags: node.js, vonage

I am using `"@vonage/server-sdk": "2.10.7-beta-2"` package on server to create users in Vonage.
To create the user, I used this API

```
const Vonage = require('@vonage/server-sdk');

const v = new Vonage({
 apiKey: config.voipConfig.key,
 apiSecret: config.voipConfig.secret,
 applicationId: config.voipConfig.appId,
 privateKey: config.voipConfig.privateKeyPath
};

v.users.create({
 "name": payload.username,
 "display_name": payload.displayName
}, (error: any, result: any) => {
});
```

Everything was working fine. But when I created a new application in vonage account and used new configs, it started to throw the following error

```
{
      description: 'You did not provide a valid token. Please provide a valid token.',
      code: 'system:error:invalid-token'
    }
```

I have checked the details multiple times and not sure what is wrong.
The new credentials are from completely new account.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Any chance the new account credentials requires signed HTTP calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are using the Vonage [Conversations API](https://github.com/Vonage/vonage-node-code-snippets/tree/master/conversation) to create a user. In good practice, we usually use `dotenv` to store our `.env` variables. If you are using a public github repo, remember to add `*.env` to your `.gitignore`.

`npm install dotenv`

```js
// .env
API_KEY=
API_SECRET=
APPLICATION_ID=
APPLICATION_PRIVATE_KEY_PATH=
TO_NUMBER=<YOUR CELL NUMBER>
VIRTUAL_NUMBER=<VONAGE VIRTUAL NUMBER>
NGROK_URL=https://<URL>.ngrok.io
```

For testing purposes. Can you make an outbound call with the snippet below? That'll test your credentials.

Make sure to store the `private.key` in same directory as `.env` and `outbound-call.js`

```
// outbound-call.js 
require("dotenv").config();
const API_KEY = process.env.API_KEY;
const API_SECRET = process.env.API_SECRET;
const APPLICATION_ID = process.env.APPLICATION_ID;
const APPLICATION_PRIVATE_KEY_PATH = process.env.APPLICATION_PRIVATE_KEY_PATH;
const TO_NUMBER = process.env.TO_NUMBER;
const VIRTUAL_NUMBER = process.env.VIRTUAL_NUMBER;
if (!API_KEY || !API_SECRET) {
  console.log(" API_KEY or API_SECRET missing");
  process.exit(1);
}
if (!APPLICATION_ID || !APPLICATION_PRIVATE_KEY_PATH) {
  console.log(" APPLICATION_ID or APPLICATION_PRIVATE_KEY_PATH missing");
  process.exit(1);
}
if (!TO_NUMBER || !VIRTUAL_NUMBER) {
  console.log(" TO_NUMBER or VIRTUAL_NUMBER missing");
  process.exit(1);
}
const Vonage = require("@vonage/server-sdk");
const vonage = new Vonage({
  apiKey: API_KEY,
  apiSecret: API_SECRET,
  applicationId: APPLICATION_ID,
  privateKey: APPLICATION_PRIVATE_KEY_PATH,
});

vonage.calls.create({
  to: [
    {
      type: "phone",
      number: process.env.TO_NUMBER,
    },
  ],
  from: {
    type: "phone",
    number: process.env.VIRTUAL_NUMBER,
  },
  ncco: [
    {
      action: "talk",
      text: "This is a text to speech call from Vonage",
    },
  ],
});
```

To test the Conversations API, you will need to enable Voice for your Vonage Application and set the `answer` Webhook. I use NGROK as well, so it should look like this. `https://<URL>.ngrok.io/webhooks/answer`

When working with Conversations API, I usually do:

1. Create a Conversation
2. Create a User
3. Create a Member

and put that into the `/webhooks/answer`

```js
//server.js
require('dotenv').config();
let express = require('express');
let cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
let logger = require('morgan');
let app = express();
let port = 5001;
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static('public'));

const NGROK_URL = process.env.NGROK_URL;

const Vonage = require('@vonage/server-sdk');
const vonage = new Vonage({
  apiKey: process.env.API_KEY,
  apiSecret: process.env.API_SECRET,
  applicationId: process.env.APPLICATION_ID,
  privateKey: process.env.APPLICATION_PRIVATE_KEY_PATH
});

app.post('/webhooks/answer', async (req, res) => {
  console.log('  answer', req.body);
  let result = req.body;

  const createCallConversationPromise = (ConvName, ConvDisplayName) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    vonage.conversations.create({
        "name": ConvName,
        "display_name": ConvDisplayName,
    }, (error, result) => error ? reject(error) : resolve(result));
  });

  const createCallUserPromise = (Name, DisplayName) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    vonage.users.create({
        name: Name,
        display_name: DisplayName,
    }, (error, result) => error ? reject(error) : resolve(result));
  });

  const createCallMemberPromise = (ConvId, UserId) => {
    vonage.conversations.members.create(ConvId, {
      "action": "join", 
      "user_id": UserId, 
      "channel": {
        "type": "app"
      } 
    }, (error, result) => {
      if(error) {
        console.log('\n Error Creating Member', error);
      }
      else {
        console.log('\n✅ Created Member with ConvId', ConvId, 'and UserId',UserId)
        console.log(result);
    }
    })
  };

  try {
    let ConvName = result.from + result.to + result.conversation_uuid;
    console.log('n✅ ConvName', ConvName);
    let ConvDisplayName = result.from + result.to + result.conversation_uuid;
    const conversation = await createCallConversationPromise(ConvName, ConvDisplayName);
    process.env.CONVERSATION_ID = conversation.id;
    console.log('\n✅ CONVERSATION_ID', process.env.CONVERSATION_ID);

    let Name = result.from + result.conversation_uuid;
    let DisplayName = result.from;
    const callUser = await createCallUserPromise(Name, DisplayName);
    console.log('\n✅ UserId', callUser.id)

    let ConvId = conversation.id;
    let UserId = callUser.id;
    const memberUser = await createCallMemberPromise(ConvId, UserId);

    let ncco = [
      {
          action: "talk",
          text: "<speak><lang xml:lang='en-GB'>Welcome to Vonage Development inbound call testing</lang></speak>",
          voiceName: "Emma"
      },
    ];
    res.json(ncco);
  
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(" Error", error);
    let ncco = [
      {
          "action": "talk",
          "text": "<speak><lang xml:lang='en-GB'>Error on Process Answer</lang></speak>",
          "voiceName": "Emma"
      }
    ];
    res.json(ncco);
  }
});
```